# Please resolve python "magic" in this calculation

Tags: python

I created a script that should perform simple math juggling by rearranging numbers.

What it should do:

```
x = 777.0
y = 5
calc = x / y # 155.4
```

...
Pseudocode:

```
Rearrange numbers (last digit + first) = 555.
Difference from 777 and 555 = 222
Add 222 to 555 = 777
```

Basically it should recreate the original variable without doing a real calculation but instead just rearrange numbers and add.

Because of the design of the script i expected it to work only with 4 digit numbers like 333.3. It turns out that it (seems to) work also with numbers like 2543.6452 wich seems to be impossibe at least from my (non academic) view.
Can someone please tell me what happens here? Is the code working correctly or did i create something i simply dont understand? It looks like a illusion to me. :D

```
x = 5.0
y = 7345.3297
z= y / x
print "Initial Value = " + str(y)
print "Calculate:"
print str(y) + "/" + str(x) 
print z # 177.6
print
a = int(str(z)[0])
print "First Number = " + str(a)
print
b = int(str(z)[1])
c = int(str(z)[2])
print "In between = " + str(b) + str(c)
d = int(str(z)[-1]) # treat z as string, take first string after . from z and format it back to int
print "Last Number = " + str(d)
print
print "Rearrange Numbers"
res = str(a+d) +str(b) +str(c)
to_int = int(res)
dif = y - to_int
add = to_int + dif
print "number = " + str(add)
```

Comment: So the code is doing exactly what you want it to do.....and....you want to know how it's doing it?

Comment: Not really. It does too much and too good. :D
If for instance, i take the number 23135.34674 and perform the calculations it should have a very different result than 23135.34674.
The code is intended (at least i expected that) to work only with "symmetric" values like 666.666 or 888.8: To me it looks like my code only takes the variable y and prints it as result. :D

The value of "in_between" only takes the second and third digit into account. It looks impossible to get the correct result with larger numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do some substitution here. The bottom lines read:

```
dif = y - to_int
add = to_int + dif
```

This can be written in one line as:

```
add = y - to_int + to_int
```

or:

```
add = y
```

So you do all this "magic" and then completely ignore it to print what you started with. You could put anything above this, all this code does at the end is print y :-)

Comment: Why is dif not y - to_int? If to_int is 555 and y is 777 i expected dif to be 222. If you run the code with a longer (non symmetric) float, it should output something completely different because there are only parts of z left. All further calculation bases on z. With "dif = y - to_int" i only want to substract the rearranged z from y.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the comment. Indeed dif is y - to_int. But I'm not sure why that matters. At the end you print a quantity called "add" that quantity is *exactly* equal to y. To demonstrate this do something like `to_int = to_int * 129736912876348723564`  before the line `dif = y - to_int` and the code will still just print `y` at the end. (Unless this causes a int/float overflow)

Comment: I tested the value of dif now and it is not the same as y!
To me this seems that my theory is true and every calculation based on number / 5 can be undone without calculating result * 5 but instead rearrange numbers. Is this crazy or is it my spaghetti monster mind illusion thing?! o_0

Comment: Here is what you are doing: `b = a / 5.` -> Do a bunch of completely unused calculations -> `print a`. Say "Look I got `a` back from `b`. "

Comment: LOL Fail! Thanks for pointing that out. This is a logical failure. Now i got it... xD